# PostgreSQL: generate a random number each hour

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to generate a random number for the count? I want to use it as a unique identifier for a count I am doing. Here is a sample query:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct bt.id) AS count,
       <insert unique id here>       
FROM boats bt
WHERE bt.created_at >= current_date AND
      bt.created_at < current_date + INTERVAL '1 day' AND
      bt.state != 'deactivated';
```

I want it to generate a new number *every hour*.

Desired output

```
count    id
23     432543
```

Above ID should be updated every hour.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help, assuming you don't simply want an answer to the effect of `random()`.

Comment: Do you generate the COUNT every hour?

Comment: Why don't you use the current date + the current hour as a unique identifier? Generating a random number wouldn't ensure it to be unique.

Comment: Does it have to be random?  Why not just an autoincrementing id?  Can it be a GUID?

Comment: @VincentSavard, yes.  Perhaps simply:  `date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp)`

Comment: Like so?

`SELECT COUNT(distinct bt.id) AS "Number of Boats Started",
       DATE_TRUNC('hour', current_timestamp) AS "id"
FROM boats bt
WHERE bt.created_at >= current_date AND
      bt.created_at < current_date + INTERVAL '1 day' AND
      bt.state != 'deactivated';`

Sorry for poor formatting. Paste it into the editor.

Comment: @DBE7, yes.  For safety you want to make that `...current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC'` so you aren't frustrated by repeated hours when daylight savings changes happen.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want this:

```
SELECT h.hh, COUNT(distinct bt.id) AS count,
FROM generate_series(0, 23) h(hh) LEFT JOIN
     boats bt JOIN
     ON extract(hour from bt.created_at) = h.hh AND
        bt.created_at >= current_date AND
        bt.created_at < current_date + INTERVAL '1 day' AND
        bt.state <> 'deactivated'
GROUP BY h.hh
ORDER BY h.hh;
```

There is no "random" number in this.  If you really want to turn this into an identifier, use a YYYYMMDDHH format or use the hour as the seed for the random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct bt.id) AS count,
       to_char(now(),'YYYYMMDDHH24')::integer AS ID
FROM boats bt
WHERE bt.created_at >= current_date AND
      bt.created_at < current_date + INTERVAL '1 day' AND
      bt.state != 'deactivated';
```